# Internet Explorer 8 'background-color' issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, compatibility, background-color

When viewing **http://joelkidd.co.uk/test** in 75% of browsers, the site look fine. However, as usual, anything less than Internet Explorer 9 and the site looks like a bomb has hit it. I sat down this morning to create a separate stylesheet for it and I am doing that right now, however I have hit a problem (this is my first bit of cross-compatibility work etc).

When I set a background-color on the header element (and other divs, for that matter), it is completely ignored. If you view the site in any (most) other browsers you will see a large velvet background that covers the top 20% (roughly) of the page.

If anyone could tell me why this is happening I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks,
Joel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel your pain. I think I might know your problem. You need to include this little bit of javasctipt code: https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Because you are using HTML5 tags for example `<header>` IE6, 7 and 8 have no idea what they mean. By including that little bit of javascript code it will basically make the HTML5 elements appear more like a `<div>` to IE6, 7 and 8

Of course your other option is to change all of the HTML5 elements to `<div>` for example: `<div id="header">` instead of `<header>`.
This would also mean changing all of your CSS as well.

Comment: Let me know if this helps you out.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks very much Andrew! I had a feeling it might be to do with the HTML5 semantics I just didn't experiment! Great answer!

Comment: A second comment to thank you. That single correction just made everything work perfectly saving me hours of work. You sir, are a legend. If there's anything I can do to help you out just let me know, you amazing human being!